# O que é um covered index?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, índices

Para que serve um índice de cobertura de um banco de dados? O que ganhamos com seu uso? Funciona em qualquer banco de dados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É uma forma de otimização. Basta colocar no índice todas as colunas necessárias para uma ou mais *queries* importantes que precisam de grande desempenho, conforme especificação de quem criou a base de dados.

Se a coluna vai junto do índice, mesmo que não precise dela como parte da chave de acesso, tem a vantagem de achar o que deseja e já poder pegar os dados necessários no próprio índice sem ter que acessar a tabela de dados, o que obviamente economiza um acesso. Mais ainda, é provável que o índice esteja na memória porque os sistemas de banco de dados costumam ser agressivos no cache de índices mais que as tabelas.

Pode ter ganhos especialmente onde tem junções (`join`) ou em certos casos complexos que pode até mesmo ajudar o planejador ter um caminho melhor por ter essa informação como mais provável de estar em *cache*.

Se uma *query* é feita e inclui uma única coluna que não está no *covering* a otimização se perde porque será necessário acesso à tabela principal. Ainda pode ter algum ganho em alguns casos, mas não é tão comum. Acessar a tabela inclusive polui o cache e influencia outras buscas.

Obviamente que colocar muitas colunas pode poluir o cache também e prejudicar outras *queries*, então tem que tomar cuidar para dosar bem, e até pode ser útil fazer manutenção disso.

Em geral não tem nada de especial nele, apenas tem as colunas que interessam. Por isso é comum não ver as pessoas usando o termo, é mais um conceito do que um mecanismo especial, então não tendo que aprender para usar, parece que não tem um termo para isso.

Para realmente acontecer o *covering*, além do sistema permitir usar várias colunas, ele precisa fazer a otimização normal de índices, se não tiver uma vantagem em acessar o índice sem precisar atingir a tabela, então ele não acontece.

Não deve ser usado como modelo básico, só serve para otimizar acesso dentro das circunstâncias.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).